# How to access Kafka event key from Druid

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I have managed to connect my Druid instance to Kafka and can see events data while defining Spec.
I would like to access the Key of the Kafka event since its contain some fields I would like to incorporate to my rollup.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:
Currently no. There is no kafka-aware format that can access the key.

Longer answer:
One can create a custom InputFormat to support this functionality.

I will try to create such a InputFormat for learning the internal of Druid and to fulfil my requirement.

If anything useful will come out of it I will try to contribute it.